# Можно ли задать ключ для input

Tags: php, html

Есть простая форма

```
<form action="/prod" method="post">
  <label form="">Цена</label>
  <input type="text" name="prod[]" value="100">
  <br>
  <label form="">Кол-во</label>
  <input type="text" name="prod[]" value="100">
  <br>
</form>
```

Форма работает без `js`

Возможно ли для `input` задать ключ, чтобы на стороне сервера видеть откуда данные?

Сейчас приходит в массиве вида -

```
Array ( [0] => 100, [1] => 100 )
```

А хотелось бы видеть -

```
Array ( "Цена" => 100, "Кол-во" => 100 )
```

Comment: Вы пишете неправду. Сейчас приходит в виде массива Array ([prod] => Array ( [0] => 100, [1] => 100 ))

Comment: В вопросе указал вывод из `$_POST['prod']`

Comment: Вы в вопросе пишете не про $_POST['prod'], а про форму. То есть - неправду

Comment: @Ипатьев Если так разобраться, то я и не указывал, что этот массив приходит с формы, это додумали Вы. Возможно вопрос задан некорректно, но как Ваше замечание может способствовать решению данного вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Возможно ли для input задать ключ, чтобы на стороне сервера видеть откуда данные?*

Не возможно, а **необходимо** задавать внятные <s>ключи</s> **имена** пост-переменным:

```
<form action="/prod" method="post">
    <label form="">Цена</label>
    <input type="text" name="price" value="100">
    <br>
    <label form="">Кол-во</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="100">
    <br>
</form>
```

А на стороне сервера вы получаете к ним доступ в суперглобальном массиве $_POST:

```
print_r($_POST['price']); // Цена
print_r($_POST['quantity']); // Кол-во
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если должно быть одно имя?

Comment: @nicolaa сохраните пост в переменную: `$prod = $_POST;` и будет у вас одно имя с доступом по ключам: `$prod['price'];  // Цена`, `$prod['quantity'];  // Кол-во`